# Python code completion in Kate, what is the status?

Tags: kde, kate

Looking for a Python code completion in Kate, I have found [this](https://pypi.org/project/Kate-plugins/) but this is fairly old (2013) and states that "*This repository is unmaintained, because these plugins have been added to the official repository*".

However in my Kate version (19.12.3, from Kubuntu 20.04) I don't see a way enable this and the Kate handbook doesn't mention it either.

So what am I missing?

Comment: the Kate handbook mentions LSP client for doing code completion ... https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/kate/kate.pdf ... maybe it is a separate plugin to be installed

Comment: this has a link to Kate... it may help ... https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi